# Why does Request.ServerVariables return only some values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, iis-6

I'm playing with ASP.NET that has part of the code that suppose to return the logged-in user:

```
Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]
```

but it returns nothing.

At the same time,

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_PASSWORD"]
```

Return the proper host name and password, respectively.

In C#:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]
```

also fails to show the username.

Meanwhile, using classic ASP code returns the user name properly.

I'm not an expert in ASP.NET, therefore my question is: Is it something to do with the server, or with the code itself?

Comment: You have anonymous access enabled would be my guess.

Comment: Is it in web.config? There are lines <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>

Comment: If you are using IIS 6 you can find it by loading the IIS Manager looking at the website properties under `Document Security` to see if anonymous access is enabled.

Comment: The fact you mention a web.config suggests your using IIS 7+ not IIS 6 in which case look for the `<anonymousAuthentication>` section in the `web.config` file. See [Anonymous Authentication <anonymousAuthentication>](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication)

Comment: Request.ServerVariables returns IIS 6... not sure if that is what I should look at

Comment: In that case [Changing the Account Used for Anonymous Authentication (IIS 6.0)](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9ded7af2-fcb7-4ed2-b007-e19f971f6e13.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: @user692942 Does this link work anymore? I keep getting "your request has been blocked" from Microsoft.

Comment: @TylerH it would appear not, but then I’m not surprised with Microsoft’s track record for destroying their old document links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to do with the authentication model you have turned on in .NET and also the authentication selections in your local/server IIS environment.

If you enable Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS and have System.Web authentication mode="Forms" in your web.config file, you will find that different server variables are populated.

So to answer your question, it's a little of both.

- [IIS 6 Server Variables Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90))

And for anyone on modern IIS:

- [IIS 10 Server Variables Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables)

Comment: I have changed authentication mode from Forms to Window and now AUTH_USER returns server/ldap .... Totally confusing..

Comment: ldap : lightweight directory access protocol; 


You just told your application to send authentication via the default user set up for windows communications of your machine rather than the built in IIS users via forms;

It is confusing, agreed, and as a result I rarely use the server variables unless completely necessary. (i too come from a classic asp background, where server variables were the norm) its better to use a managed .net object to query authentication because then you can breakpoint it and see values in realtime

Comment: Yeah, that was mostly for testing... It's not the best idea to use Windows authentication...